# WebApi Basic Auth Warning And GlobalConfiguration not found in context

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I recently started to learning WebApi C#, and I have one question about Basic Auth.
I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2015/04/17/basic-authentication-in-aspnet-webapi/).

The problem I`m having is a warning on this part of code.

```
public class IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute : BasicAuthenticationAttribute
{
    protected override async Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 

        if (userName != "testuser" || password != "Pass1word")
        {
            // No user with userName/password exists.
            return null;
        }

        Claim nameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName);
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> { nameClaim };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationTypes.Basic);

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal;
    }
}
```

I get the following warning:

> Advertencia   1   A este método asincrónico le faltan operadores 'await' y se ejecutará
>   de forma sincrónica. Considere el uso del operador 'await' para
>   esperar llamadas API que no sean de bloqueo o 'await Task.Run(...)'
>   para realizar tareas enlazadas a la CPU en un subproceso en segundo
>   plano.    C:\Users\Desarrollo2\Source\Repos\digitalapi\Digital.WebApi\Filters\Auth\IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute.cs    14  51  Digital.WebApi

How can I solve this or suppress that warning?

And I want to ask something else, it is not a problem but it is a boring error...

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

> Error 2   El nombre 'GlobalConfiguration' no existe en el contexto
>   actual    C:\Users\Desarrollo2\Source\Repos\digitalapi\Digital.WebApi.Tests\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs  18  13  Digital.WebApi.Tests

It is fixed cleaning solution and recompile. But if it is possible I want to know why sometimes app give me that issue.

Sorry if errors are in Spanish, I hope this is not a problem to figure out these issues.

Thanks in advance;

Sorry my bad English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because you have `async` on your method definition, but nowhere in the method invocation are you using `await`.

Remove the `async` from the method definition and return a Task to remove that warning.

```
protected override Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 

    if (userName != "testuser" || password != "Pass1word")
    {
        // No user with userName/password exists.
        return null;
    }

    Claim nameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName);
    var claims = new List<Claim> { nameClaim };

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationTypes.Basic);

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    return Task.FromResult((IPrincipal)principal);
}
```

That error can occur when the project cannot find the necessary dll for `GlobalConfiguration`.

Add reference to the assembly: System.Web.Http.WebHost dll

or make sure it is being referenced.

If you are using `NuGet` packages you should check to make sure you are using the correct packages. Look for `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.*`

Here are some tutorials

[Basic Authentication in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication)

[A WebAPI Basic Authentication Authorization Filter](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter)